# What will be the radius of the 1st circle in this question?

Tags: geometry, circles

Two circles $O_1$ (with radius $r_1$) and $O_2$ (with radius $r_2$), $r_1>r_2$, touch each other externally, and the line $m$ is a common tangent. The line $l$ is parallel to $m$ and touches $O_1$ and the circle $O_3$( with radius $r_3$) touches $l$ and the two given circles externally. If $r_2$ is $3$ and $r_3$ is $5$, find $r_1$.

[image]

What I tried:
I found the common tangent length between $O_1$, $O_3$ and $O_2$, $O_1$. However, I couldn't proceed further.

Thanks for reading! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $d_3$ and $d_2$ are the common tangent lengths between $O_1$, $O_3$ and $O_1$, $O_2$, then consider the right triangle having hypothenuse $r_2+r_3$ and catheti $2r_1-r_2-r_3$, $d_3-d_2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My bad - It's my first post on this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As shown in the picture with Pythagorean triangles, we can form the equation

$$\sqrt{12r} + \sqrt{32r-4r^2} = \sqrt{20r}$$

Simplfy,

$$\sqrt{32-4r} = \sqrt{20} - \sqrt{12}$$

$$32 - 4r = 32 - 2\sqrt{240}$$

$$r = \sqrt{60}$$

Comment: How can we say that the centres are a part of a rectangle?

Comment: We construct the three Pythagorean triangles separately. They form an rectangle because of the right angles.